# Prove that N((0,0); 1) is an open set in R x R with the metric $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))= max( |x_1 - y_1| , |x_2 - y_2| )$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm very stuck and just generally don't know how to start. I thought maybe start with 
$x \in N((0,0),1)$ 
but I'm not sure where to go based on the definition now. I think because it's a max I need to do two cases?

Comment: Is an open set for which topology?

Comment: @ mathcounterexamples.net. The topology is obviously induced by the given metric.

Comment: @user10072477 You need to show that given a point $(x,y)\in N((0,0);1)$ we can find a $\delta>0$ such that $N((x,y);\delta)\subset N((0,0);1)$